# What should I do so I can upload different files for iOS

Tags: ios7, xcode5, app-store-connect

I had an app in iOS. Now I create another APP and I want to upload the same program as that other APP.

The problem is, how can Xcode knows that this program already points to the new program?

Bundle ID? App ID?

How to identify in xcode that this is the program for what program?

In other words:
How does xcode knows which app belong to the archive?

Is it by bundle id?

If I uploaded an APP and then create another APP in itunes connect, what should I do to do the itunes connect?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: `IOS` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisco_IOS) isn't the same as `iOS` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS) please phrase correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Short Answer is Bundle ID.

When you validate or distribute any app from Xcode to iTune it search for Bundle ID in your account and work according to that.

Your provisioning Profile have information about your Bundle ID and App ID. So set proper Bundle ID and provisioning as you do for previous app upload.